# Facebook Ads SDK for .net core that use Facebook Marketing api v5.0

Tags: facebook, asp.net-core, facebook-graph-api

I tried to find Facebook Ads sdk for .net core, but i find only skds that use deprecated version of Facebook Marketing api, and for this reason not working. Anyone know a updated sdk?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no updated SDK. Just use a `HTTPClient` and consume Rest endpoints with GET and POST requests. It's very easy to use.

Starts with the [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/) and look for the cURL examples to see how you need to construct your queries.